# Finding a Non-Primitive Root Mod N

Tags: discrete-mathematics, factoring, primitive-roots

Given a large random (prime or composite) N, how do I find $a$ (non-trivial: $a\neq1$ and $a\neq{N-1}$) and $b<N/2$ such that $a^b=1 \bmod N$ as quickly as possible?

I'm guessing I need to factor N to get the totient, but hoping there is some faster trick.

For example, what $a$ and $b$ work for the following $N$?

535681323635377947803477563729034842741283197685482147845846116229490072327829772255980786581056231891824965196685872407087235634574765922267452145891219949840333521605137458047897130486331989436075480864422748548516493270268959879090425463

Comment: Take $a = N-1$ and $b = 2$.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to avoid both a=1 and a=-1...will edit.

Comment: Anyway, in your example, $a = 2$ and $b = 1024$ work. That is, if you don't avoid $a = 2$...

Comment: Guess I really shouldn't be using the Mersenne form...thanks for helping, please wait for the edit.

Comment: I don't know what you exactly want. In your modified example, of course $a = 2$ and $b = 2048$ work. Also $a = 4$ and $b = 1024$, or $a = 16$ and $b = 512$, etc. It is very easy to get non-primitive elements, as a random number will be non-primitive with high probability.

Comment: OK, forget the Mersenne-like form, I'm going to actually generate a random number and edit my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you are struggling with giving an example, let me mention that it is in general not easy to find the order of an element $a$ modulo $N$.

Think about the case when $N = pq$ is a product of two different prime numbers. If you pick a random number $a$ modulo $N$, then there is a significant probability that $a$ is in fact a primitive root modulo both $p$ and $q$. Thus knowing the order of $a$ modulo $N$ will likely let you know $\phi(N)$, and that again implies that you know the factorization of $N$.

Therefore a factorization of $N$ seems unavoidable to me.

Of course, once $N$ is factorized, you know everything and the task becomes trivial.

Comment: So, I would factor N to get the totient, then pick a random a, then try b which are divisors of that totient, then repeat with a different random a if no divisor works, right?  I guess after a few different a, I'm likely to have stumbled across a non-primitive root and therefore solve my problem.  OK, factorization looks unavoidable like you say.

Comment: Looks like I just need to find one factor so it's often not as slow as I thought. In my random example, since 3 factors N, one can immediately see a solution: $(N/3−1)^2=1$